# Sending Signals to Multiprocess in C (Linux)

Tags: c, arrays, process, signals, fork

I created multiple processes in a loop and saved every pid in a global array. I thought that this would be visible to all created processes. But whenever I try to send signals using this array, all values seem as 0 (zero). I don't know to make this array visible and keep updated for all processes to use. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As an easier alternative, look into using process groups and sending a signal to all the processes in that group at once.

Answer (score 0):

`fork`ed processes do not share memory.  Each process, after a `fork`, will functionally contain a *copy* of the memory space of the original (it's Copy On Write, so it will be copied when it's changed, but they're functionally distinct after the fork).

This simple examples shows how every child can see the global children array *in its own process space*, as of the `fork()`, but not thereafter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MCHILD 3
pid_t children[MCHILD];

void print_children(char* prefix){
  for( int i = 0; i < MCHILD; i++){
    printf("%s sees child element %i: %d\n", prefix, i, children[i]);
  }
}

int main() {
  for( int i = 0; i < MCHILD; i++){
    pid_t p = fork();
    if(p == 0){
      printf("Child %d\n", i);
      char * prefix;
      asprintf(&prefix, "\tChild %d", i);
      print_children(prefix);
      exit(0);
    } else {
      children[i] = p;
    }
  }
  print_children("Parent");
}
```

Here it is running:

```
$ gcc -o tc t.c && ./tc
Parent sees child element 0: 41188
Parent sees child element 1: 41189
Parent sees child element 2: 41190
Child 0
    Child 0 sees child element 0: 0
    Child 0 sees child element 1: 0
    Child 0 sees child element 2: 0
Child 1
    Child 1 sees child element 0: 41188
    Child 1 sees child element 1: 0
    Child 1 sees child element 2: 0
Child 2
    Child 2 sees child element 0: 41188
    Child 2 sees child element 1: 41189
    Child 2 sees child element 2: 0
```

Comment: If you want shared memory, you can use threads instead of processes, or one of a few inter-process shared memory (`mmap` probably being the most straightforward). But this has its own issues, namely, coordinating shared memory access.  multiprocessing and inter-process communications is where a higher level language like `golang` really shines... C is, as is typical for the language, batteries-not-included.